# Can not install packages in Atom (ERROR: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND)

Tags: npm, package, atom-editor

Either throught apm command or in Atom setting screen can not install packages,It seems a proxy problem, but what IP and port should I use?
I just use laptop at home not in company,Pls see the error screenshot and my apm config

BTW, I use windows OS
[ERROR info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1X48.png)